# Waveform issues with inverting amplifier

Tags: pcb, amplifier, circuit-analysis, inverting-amplifier

I'm trying to achieve a gain of exactly -1, however the output of this circuit isn't the expected waveform (correct gain, just wrong wave).

Is there an issue with the circuit?

[image: Schematic]
[image: Board]

Comment: This was explained in your previous question raised yesterday. Which bit of "you need a negative supply on pin 11" do you not understand?

Comment: I've never used negative voltage before, only DC microcontroller circuits unfortunately. Was under the impressing that negative simply meant ground...

Comment: I apologize for the influx of questions, just trying grind out a high school science fair!

Comment: What you have is an inverting amplifier - if the input is positive (Vcc on your earlier question) then the output has to be negative. Op-amps can't magic negative voltages from thin-air - they need a supply voltage span that is greater than the output voltage span.

Answer (score 0):

The negative power supply of your OpAmp is just GND (0V). It definitely needs to be more negative than the most negative output and input value.

How much more negative depends on the type of OpAmp; see datasheet.

I also recommend to not leave the inputs of the unused OpAmps unconnected.

Comment: Thanks for that! How can I create a negative voltage? Could I use a bench power supply (I have a rigol dp832) but have never needed to use -v .

Comment: Use a power supply that provides both positive and negative voltages. If you have only positive supply you can create it from postive supply, e.g. using a TL7660 (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl7660.pdf) followed by a (preferably low-drop) negative voltage regulator.

Comment: Another way is to create your new reference voltage between V+ and the GND (e.g. by voltage divider and OpAmp buffer) and have your signals referenced to it. That is the easiest solution for your problem but works only if you are free to chosse the reference voltage of your signals.

Comment: Awesome, I just found a -12v supply lying around! Thanks for the advice (:

Comment: Ahh, the divider/buffer solution makes sense. Ill give it a go tomorrow (thanks again!)

Comment: @user96033  Remember this. the inverting input gain is always relative to Vin+ so for symmetry choose Vcc/2 for V+in with 2 equal R's as a reference. Then check if the Op Amp works near supply or ground (Rail-to-Rail type only) Some work near Vcc others near V- or gnd on single supply, usually not both..